# How to get the current paragraph name?

Tags: cobol

I would like to know how to get the current paragraph name in COBOL (using MVS Enterprise COBOL V4.2 here).

Let's say I have this code in the PROCEDURE DIVISION :

```
   MAIN-LOGIC.
       MOVE SPACE TO ABT-MSG
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH-1
       PERFORM PARAGRAPH-2
       GO TO CLOSE-PROGRAM.
  *
  * SEARCH FOR A VALUE IN AN ARRAY AND GET THE RELATED INDEX
  *
   PARAGRAPH-1.
       MOVE 42 TO SEARCH-VALUE
       PERFORM VARYING I-SEARCH FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL SOME-ARRAY(I-SEARCH) = SEARCH-VALUE
         IF (I-SEARCH = MAX-ARRAY-POSITION)
           MOVE SEARCH-ABORT TO ABT-MSG
           MOVE 'PARAGRAPH-1' TO ABT-LOC
           GO TO CLOSE-PROGRAM
         END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       DISPLAY 'VALUE WAS FOUND AT POSITION ' I-SEARCH '.'.
  *
  * STORE A NEW VALUE AT THE END OF AN ARRAY
  *
   PARAGRAPH-2.
       MOVE 42 TO STORAGE-VALUE
       ADD 1 TO I-STORAGE
       IF (I-STORAGE > MAX-ARRAY-POSITION)
         MOVE STORAGE-ABORT TO ABT-MSG
         MOVE 'PARAGRAPH-2' TO ABT-LOC
         GO TO CLOSE-PROGRAM
       END-IF
       MOVE STORAGE-VALUE TO SOME-ARRAY(I-STORAGE).
  *
  * CLOSE THE PROGRAM
  *
   CLOSE-PROGRAM.
       IF ABT-MSG > SPACE
         DISPLAY ABT-MSG
         DISPLAY '(FOUND IN ' ABT-LOC ')'
         MOVE 20 TO RETURN-CODE
       ELSE
         DISPLAY SUCCESS-MESSAGE
       END-IF
       STOP RUN.
```

I would like to be able to access the current paragraph name (and store it in ABT-LOC) instead of having to write it.
Is there a COBOL system variable to do so, like 'CURR-PARA-NAME' or something ?

Thank you.

------ UPDATE 1 -------

I have updated my code example to make it more specific.
Know that, in my real COBOL program, there are various occurences of SEARCH-ABORT and STORAGE-ABORT possibilities (I am working with many arrays).

I want to make my code as good as possible, hence my will to access the current paragraph name instead of having to write it.

Thank you again.

------- UPDATE 2 ------

Well then. It seems I cannot do it (the users of my program will probably reject any debug messages they are not used to get - For your information, I am rewriting a 50 years old program with very, very bad programming practices such as upward GO TOs, fall-through logic and the godforsaken ALTER, and I want to get the same output at the end).

Don't worry, I will not cry tonight. This was just an esthetical improvement to my code, and I can live without it (my code is already a lot prettier than what I based myself on).

I thank all of you for your time, and wish you a good... Stack Overday !

Comment: Which COBOL compiler are you using?

Comment: Like Bill, said.  There is a new-ish extension in GnuCOBOL to expose certain hosted variables, and I just did a small experiment to return pointers to the step trace data.   That includes current program-id (there are other ways of getting that one), section, paragraph, source file, and line number.  Seems like a worthy add to CBL_OC_HOSTED, but does require `-ftrace` or `-ftraceall` set during compile for executables to track step tracer data.  When it goes in, it'll be `CALL "CBL_OC_HOSTED" USING paraptr "paragraph" RETURNING err-indicator`.  `paraptr` set to a `char *` on success.

Comment: @BrianTiffin you should write it up. I was going a different route...

Comment: There is always the option of adding your own pre-compiler step

Comment: Alternatively depending on your editor, you could setup a edit macro. ISPF editor / rexx is good for things like this. I suspect this could be done in  jedit and some of the other advanced editors

Comment: @BillWoodger, just opened a request for comment in the Contributions forum, Bill.  Sounds like we're going to make a new intrinsic or two, as the idea got a good reception.  In line with the MODULE-xxx functions.

Comment: I was not sure of the compiler version my company was using (for your information, we are working with a mainframe, and JCLs are used to compile and execute our COBOL programs), so I looked at the compilation output. I found the following line :
"PP 5655-S71 IBM Enterprise COBOL for z/OS  4.2.0" (yes, 420 blaze it, I know)
If that does not help, the job step compiling my program is called 'COBMVS'. Maybe MVS is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Enterprise COBOL V4.2 is the answer, thanks. Until three years ago, 4.2 was top-of-the-notch, so don't worry about that. V5.2 or V6.1 may be along for you anytime soon (your mileage may vary).

Comment: You can access the compiler's documentation at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036733 - `FUNCTION EXCEPTION-LOCATION` isn't available (isn't in 6.1, too), adding the DEBUG-ITEM to my answer just for reference...
@BillWoodger: I'm interested in the route you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the pseudo-code "something bad happened here" I assume an exception. In this case the standard (COBOL 2002, COBOL 2014) function `EXCEPTION-LOCATION` may help (although the actual string is implementor-defined I assume the paragraph may be in there [GnuCOBOL for example has the format: program-id; paragraph [or paragraph OF section or section, depending on your program]; source-line]).

If your COBOL compiler provides this information in this function and there is no exception in the offending part already: create one via `subtract 1 from unsigned-var` or similar.

As Bill already said (or implied): this is a question where the actual COBOL compiler used will be the most important part if you must have the names in as identifier and as label or not.

***Edit*** (after the actual COBOL compiler is known):

IBM MVS Enterprise COBOL doesn't have the `EXCEPTION-LOCATION` function. Therefore I see only one built-in solution:

```
DECLARATIVES.
debug-declaratives SECTION.
   USE FOR DEBUGGING ON ALL PROCEDURES.
debug-par.
    MOVE debug-name  TO current-procedure.
END DECLARATIVES.
```

But as this is only active if your program runs in debugging-mode (which may causes a lot of debugging messages to occur) **I don't suggest to actual use this**.

Try to use an Editor providing macros (or run a shell script on your actual source) to create the source you pass to the compiler afterwards.

Comment: I have updated my code example with more specific situations. I wouldn't consider them EXCEPTIONS, but rather Business errors.

Comment: Yes, the debugging declarative is the only way to actually do it, and it shouldn't be done that way.

Comment: You gave me a valid solution (that I just cannot apply), so I will mark your answer as being the most helpful. Good day to you.

Answer (score 4):

As Simon Sobisch has correctly indicated in his answer, the only way to do exactly what you want is to use the "debugging declaratives". See later in the answer for making that work, but no-one should allow you to do this to a Production program.

COBOL is a compiled language so there is no no automatic access to any data-name or procedure name (paragraph or SECTION) unless the compiler makes something available. Which, excluding the case above, it doesn't.

That leaves three approaches: doing it manually (which you correctly want to avoid, as sure as peaches someone is going to copy or relocate code without changing the literal); pre-processing (with a program or the editor) to automatically populate your field with the correct label; doing something else.

Since you are implicitly discounting the first, again I believe correctly, let's consider the second. What if you have two, three or eight things in the same paragraph/SECTION which are all "business errors" (although usually these types of things are more "integrity errors", a state which should not exist, so don't continue)?

Since you will get those, a "pre-processing" solution starts to get more ugly.

What else can be done?

Well, it's something we've faced for many, many years. The answer is, unique (within the program) error numbers. The individual errors can be named, well, and given a number. The well-named error reference is difficult to use "incorrectly". When adding a new error, it is difficult to duplicate an existing number. Or, to put it another way, it is easy to duplicate but horribly easy to spot in testing - "hey, that's produced 1234, that's wrong".

It's in no way bullet-proof, but the data-name (and any associated text) give better indication of the problem than a paragraph-name (which is not going to be, except artificially, any indication of what the error is, just the location of it). The error references are very easy to find in the program, and from that it is easy to locate the procedure name, except you don't actually need it any more.

Whether the program with error-numbers outweigh the dross of manually maintained MOVE 'literal' TO some-standard-name programs is unknown. But you can guess which I favour and recommend.

Now, how to do it for Enterprise COBOL with DECLARATIVES.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. STAB39. 
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
   CONFIGURATION SECTION. 
   SOURCE-COMPUTER. FRED DEBUGGING MODE. 

   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  W-WHEN-COMPILED                     PIC X(8)BX(8).
   01  ABT-LOC                             PIC X(30). 


   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
  DDECLARATIVES. 
  DSOME-SECTION SECTION. 
  D    USE FOR DEBUGGING ON ALL PROCEDURES 
  D    . 
  DSOME-PARA. 
  D    MOVE DEBUG-NAME TO ABT-LOC 
  D    . 
  DEND DECLARATIVES. 
   STARTING-UP SECTION. 
       DISPLAY 
               ABT-LOC 
  D    DISPLAY 
  D            "IT IS STARTING UP" 
       MOVE WHEN-COMPILED           TO W-WHEN-COMPILED 
       DISPLAY 
               "STAB39 " 
               W-WHEN-COMPILED 
       . 
   A-PARA. 
       DISPLAY 
               ABT-LOC 
       PERFORM 
         10 TIMES 
  D        DISPLAY 
                   "ITERATING" 
       END-PERFORM 
       . 
   ANOTHER-PARA. 
       DISPLAY 
               ABT-LOC 
       PERFORM                      THE-PARA 
                                     10 TIMES 
       PERFORM                      THE-SECOND-PARA 
       GOBACK 
       . 
   THE-PARA. 
       DISPLAY 
               ABT-LOC 
       . 
   THE-SECOND-PARA. 
       DISPLAY 
               ABT-LOC
       .
```

Some notes:

The SOURCE-COMPUTER paragraph is required to use COBOLs in-built debugging features, to turn them on. So the ENVIRONMENT DIVISION and CONFIGURATION SECTION are also required. The "computer name", FRED in the example, is required, but it is irrelevant. You can "name" your computer after your favourite pet or relative if you like, or put anything there, there just has to be something.

DECLARATIVES can only be specified at the start of the PROCEDURE DIVISION. They must be within a SECTION and all actions must be within a paragraph belonging to a SECTION. The names of the SECTION and paragraph are irrelevant, but make them meaningful anyway.

Because the DECLARATIVES must contain a SECTION, you will be subject to an informational diagnostic message if your first procedure label is not also a SECTION. This does not require using SECTIONS over paragraphs in your program, it has no further effect.

The D in column seven indicates a "debugging line". These lines only get code generated when you turn debugging on with the SOURCE-COMPUTER paragraph.

The program exercises all use of a paragraph (and use of a SECTION is no different for this example) except GO TO. Paragraphs which are GO TO'd will produce the same results as any other reference, but you won't see GO TOs in my programs :-)

It is possible to name the procedure or procedures you want to "trap" with the DECLARATIVES instead of using "ALL PROCEDURES".

You may have multiple DEBUGGING procedures, and you can include extensive code within them if you wish (setting up conditions for testing, for instance).

Although this feature has existed in COBOL for a long time, it is probably fair to say that it is not widely used, especially as specific "debugging products" became available.

It is not enough just to have this program, the "run time" needs to have DEBUG turned on, if it is not the default. The run-time on z/OS is called Language Environment and is shared by multiple languages (allowing easy inter-language communication). Languages include C/C++, PL/I and Java as well as COBOL. There are Language Environment routines and macros available to make HLASM/Assembler programs "LE Compliant" to also provide ready interfacing.

To see what run-time options your site has as default, the easiest thing to do is to include a CEEOPTS DD statement in your run JCL.

```
//CEEOPTS  DD  *
   RPTOPTS(ON)
```

This will list out all the options used for your "Enclave" (your run environment) and indicate where each option is sourced from.

If, in the OPTION column, you see NODEBUG, then COBOL debugging is turned off by default. To turn it on for a particular run:

```
//CEEOPTS  DD  *
   DEBUG
```

This will allow all the D-labelled debugging lines and the debugging DECLARATIVES to execute.

This will do what you want, but no-one will allow a program with debugging on into Production, so you can't use it for what you want.

In order of preference, I advise error-numbers (and testing), automation, hand-coded procedure-name literals.

IBM fully documents all its products, and you can find the documentation (Language Reference and Programming Guide amongst others) for Enterprise COBOL V4.2 and also Language Environment (several) for your release of z/OS.

One final point. Don't use GO TO to "break out" of your normal processing flow. Use PERFORM. Even when, logically, the PERFORM cannot return. Using GO TO will turn off compiler optimisation for paragraphs/SECTIONs containing the GO TO which can easily cause a noticeable impact on execution. This is the reverse of the advice from before IBM COBOL ensured that the state of PERFORMed paragraphs/SECTIONs is not preserved between CALLs. At that time the correct advice was to use GO TO. It is no longer the correct advice.

Comment: You are right : the location of an error often is not enough to solve said error. And I do sometimes have several abort possibilities in a single paragraph.

The objective behind my use of paragraph names is to help me or the user find what's wrong faster. But this objective can be achieved by other means, like - as you said - putting unique error numbers for each error type.

As a side note, even if I won't use your code with declaratives, I appreciate it. You clearly know a lot more than me on COBOL, and you seem to know what you're talking about.

Good day to you !